# "Insufficient virtual memory" error for allocating small arrays

Tags: fortran

I have been using Fortran for a few months now, but I am self-taught and have only been learning it by reading someone else's codes so my knowledge of Fortran is very limited. I wrote this function which is meant to read a text file containing data and save these data in an array. Since I don't know the size of the data, I choose to allocate the array within the function.

```
      FUNCTION RSEBIN(NAMEIN,NZNSEB)
      
      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H, O-Z)
      INTEGER DSEBTP, IIND, NZNSEB
      CHARACTER(LEN=75) :: FILNAM
      CHARACTER NAMEIN*(*)
      REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: RSEBIN(:,:)
      
      WRITE (FILNAM,1500) 'Extra_InputFiles/SEB_inputs/SEB_', NAMEIN,
     2    '.txt'  !Define the path and name of the input data text file
 1500 FORMAT (A32,A,A4)
      OPEN (UNIT=101, FILE=FILNAM, STATUS='OLD')
      READ(101,*) !Skip the header
      DSEBTP = 0
      DO                            
          READ(101,*,IOSTAT=IO) TRASH  
          IF (IO.NE.0) EXIT !Exit the loop when last line has been reached           
          DSEBTP = DSEBTP + 1   !Counts how many time periods inputs are set for the input data type
      END DO           
      REWIND(101)  !Rewind text file to read the inputs
      ALLOCATE(RSEBIN(DSEBTP,NZNSEB+1))  !Allocate the input data array
      READ(101,*) !Skip the header
      DO 1510 ISEBTP=1,DSEBTP
          READ(101,*) (RSEBIN(ISEBTP,IIND), IIND=1, NZNSEB+1) !Save the data in the main array
 1510 CONTINUE
      CLOSE (UNIT=101)

      RETURN
      END FUNCTION
```

I then use this function in another subroutine with this following statement:

```
ASEBAT = RSEBIN('AirTemperature',NZNSEB) !Allocate the air temperature array (first column is time)
```

When I try to run the program, I get a "Insufficient virtual memory" error. After a quick search, I discovered that this error usually occurs when one is allocating huge arrays. However, during my tests, I was only using a 3 X 5 array. After a few more tests, I realized that the function works fine if I declare the dimensions of my array RSEBIN rather than making it allocatable and allocating it in the function. However, this solution is not sustainable for me as I want this function to be able to read text files of various dimensions.

Does anyone have an idea why I have such error? Should I avoid allocating arrays in a function? As I said previously, I am fairly new to Fortran and I am pretty sure my code has many issues, so I apologize for my primitive code writing and would be grateful for any tip.

Also, I should note that I'm using the Intel Fortran Compiler from oneAPI for Windows. I recently switched from the fortran compiler in Intel XE, with which, if I can recall, I was using a similar function without any issue.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it is specifically this allocation which is causing the problem? Do you have any other memory intensive programs running when you start this? Also please use Implicit None in all your code.

Comment: Have your examined the values of DSEBTP and NZNSEB just before the allocation?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will switch to Implicit None. I think that the problem is in this allocation because there is no issue if I delete the allocation and instead declare "REAL :: RSEBIN(3,5)". Values of DSEBTP and NZNSEB are good. Actually, I get the right values in RSEBIN when I print it before the end of the function. The program stops once it goes back to my subroutine and gives ASEBAT a size of 0. My subroutine previously declares "REAL, ALLOCATABLE, SAVE :: ASEBAT(:,:)" Not really any other intensive programs running, but that's a good question. I'll reboot just in case.

Comment: Just realised you have a function returning an allocatable array. Do you have an interface in scope at the calling point? If not that could easily cause the problems you are seeing.

Comment: The RSEBIN function is correct, the use of ALLOCATE is correct. Hence the problem is in the environment. Give not a code snippet, but a small program that you can compile and run.

Comment: There is no dishonour in reading the file to a scalar dummy variable just to find the size, then doing a REWIND, allocate the memory, and read it for real,

Comment: My function is included in a module, and there is a USE (module name) in my subroutine. You are all right, the function and the allocation are fine. I tried my function in a small program and it compiles and runs smoothly. I have no idea why it doesn't work in my main program (which I can't copy here because it consists of thousands of lines). I'll keep looking for the problem in my main program. Thanks to all of you for the useful feedback!